# Microsoft Office Ribbon Custom Tabs Corrupted If Hide Standard Tabs

Tags: ms-office, customization, ribbon, cpu-word

I have created a set of custom tabs for the Microsoft Word Ribbon, which I load using tool in Word and appear in the `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\Word.officeUI` file.

They are proven to work, and the Word.officeUI file xml looks the same as my copy that I load.

However, recently I wanted to hide some standard tabs.

So I included: `<mso:tab idMso="TabWordDesign" visible="false"/>`

I then noticed my XML was being corrupted (some groups not appearing) when I closed Word, and on further investigation the Word.officeUI had changed (some of my XML vanished and all line breaks disappeared).

I could see it happening. I would load Word and import my customisation file, all looked fine in Word.officeUI, but when I closed, the Word.officeUI file changed to a fixed 18KB file (irrespective of the starting size) with just some of my xml.

I removed that xml, and the problem disappeared.

I then tried hiding the tab using the "Customise Ribbon" in Word instead.

The same problem occurred.

Essentially if I hide any standard tabs (however I do it), word corrupts my customUI when I close it.

Is this a bug I should report, or has anyone encountered and solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported scenario. If you took a look at the articles posted later you might notice the following:

> "It is not possible to override these commands from the custom UI XML markup or by using the object model... A better solution would be to consider hiding the built-in UI and rebuilding it fully with custom commands."

So, if you want to hide a built-in control or tab you need to use the `startFromScratch` mode (see the corresponding property in the ribbon markup) and rebuild the entire ribbon from the ground excluding the required controls.

Be aware, you can add built-in controls to your own tab where you can disable or hide them at runtime.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, which makes sense.  If I want to edit Normal.dotm, then there are more limitations than if I create a ribbon in my own .dotm template - I understand that know.  Those three articles are brilliant - thank you again.